# Trigger css change based on video play/pause

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm learning and not sure how to ask this but here goes. I have buttons that I made from imgs, and want to use them to play one single video and have it automatically pause at specific times and then the img's css change. Then click the next img to start playing again until the next pause. I have it almost working. How can I change the css of the imgs along with playing/pausing the videos? I want to change their display to none/block once the video plays/pauses depending on my needs. Can I integrate it in what I have here? Can I add something like `this.style.display = none/block`? Where would I add it?

```
  <video class="vid" id="myvideo" src="assets/fullvideo.mp4" playsinline muted>
  </video>
  
  <div class="btnsDiv">
    <img src="imgs/btns/start.png" data-start="00" data-end="02" id="start" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/continue.png" data-start="02" data-end="08" id="cont1" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/continue.png" data-start="08" data-end="18" id="cont2" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/yes.png" data-start="18" data-end="22" id="yes1"  />
    <img src="imgs/btns/no.png" data-start="18" data-end="22" id="no1"  />
    <img src="imgs/btns/continue.png" data-start="22" data-end="66" id="cont3" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/yes.png" data-start="66" data-end="71" id="yes2" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/no.png" data-start="66" data-end="71" id="no2" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/continue.png" data-start="71" data-end="99" id="cont4" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/admin.png" data-start="99" data-end="103" id="admin" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/judicial.png" data-start="99" data-end="103" id="judicial" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/continue.png" data-start="103" data-end="137" id="cont5" />
    <img src="imgs/btns/question.png" data-start="137" data-end="170" id="findout" />
  </div>
```

JS

```
let end;
const btns = document.querySelector('.btnsDiv');
const vid = document.querySelector('.vid');

btns.addEventListener('click', frag);
vid.addEventListener('timeupdate', stop);

function frag(event) {
    const clicked = event.target;
    if (clicked.matches('img')) {
        let start = Number(clicked.dataset.start);
        end = Number(clicked.dataset.end);
        vid.currentTime = start;
        vid.play();
    }
    return false;
}


function stop(event) {
    const vid = event.target;
    if (vid.matches('video')) {
        if (vid.currentTime >= end) {
        vid.pause();
    }
    }
// End function
return false;
}
```

Comment: Provide each video/image with an id (if the css is different for each video/image) or a class (if the css is the same for each video/image). The click handlers `pause` and `play` can then apply the css via id/class. jquery will help simplify your javascript as it has methods already to do this `addClass` and `removeClass` https://api.jquery.com/addclass/

Comment: There's no click for pause though it does it automatically based on the data-end attribute.

Comment: In your `stop` method you can apply or remove the necessary class inside the `if (vid.currentTime >= end)` block. This same logic could be re-used if you implement an `onClick` event for the video/image or any other control you want to provide

Comment: I tried this.className = etc but it would't work. Could you show an example?